# Compiling 32-bit app on 64-bit, cannot find -lX11

Tags: 64-bit, compiling

I'm invoking a command like:

```
g++ ... -o"myapp" -lX11 ...
```

And getting

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lX11
```

I've installed the following packages to support multiarch:

```
ia32-libs, libc6-dev-i386 and g++-multilib
```

But to no avail. There does not appear to be any X11.so in /usr/lib32, actually there are only 52 libraries in that directory. I'm under the impression you should manually install libraries, but I'm at a loss as to what I should check next.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the output of the command `ldconfig -p | grep libX11\\.`?

Answer (score 5):

You need the header files, which are provided by `-dev` packages, and not in the library packages themselves. So, try installing `libx11-dev`. That should fix this particular build error, though you may get similar errors about other libraries (and then you can install their `-dev` packages.)

Even though these packages provide header files rather than binaries, and in general header files account for all supported architectures through the use of preprocessor macros, nonetheless `-dev` packages in Ubuntu tend to be architecture-specific, and this is the case for `libx11-dev` (as can be seen [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libx11) by expanding a release and finding the `.deb` packages listed for `libx11-dev` in that release). Since your Ubuntu system is 64-bit and you're compiling a 32-bit program which must link against the 32-bit version of the library, you'll probably need to install the 32-bit version of `libx11-dev`. If you're installing with `apt-get` or `aptitude`, you can specify that by indicating `libx11-dev:i386` as the package to install (since [multarch](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MultiArch) is supported and being used).

http://packages.ubuntu.com/ is a good resource for finding the name of the `-dev` package corresponding to a library package. It's not always the library package's name immediately followed by `-dev`; sometimes version numbers present in the library package name, especially after a `-`, are *absent* in the name of the corresponding `-dev` package.